# How to get old value and new value of multiple field in trigger in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, audit-tables

I have a table `Person`:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Phone varchar(50),
    Address varchar(50),
    City varchar(50),
    PinCode varchar(50),
    DateOfBirth DATETIME,
    UpdatedOn DATETIME,
    UpdatedBy varchar(50)
)
```

Whenever I insert or update the multiple fields from above table then I want previous value and current value of all updated fields and store that in another table using Trigger. How we can get values of all updated fields.

For example

```
INSERT INTO Person 
VALUES (1, 'first', 'last', '11111', 'add', 'city', 'pin', GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 'ABC')

UPDATE Person
SET FirstName = 'First11', 
    LastName = 'Last22', 
    Phone = '1010101010'
WHERE id = 1
```

When I will hit above commands in both cases I want old and current value and store it in another table. How we can achieve this using triggers?

Comment: Simple - write on `AFTER INSERT` trigger, and another `AFTER UPDATE` - see [the official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server when you updated ( he delete the old values and then insert the new values )

```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[YOUR_TRIGGER_NAME_INSERT]
   ON  [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE] 
   AFTER INSERT --Here when you insered rows
   AS 
   BEGIN
        select * from inserted --get all inserted rows  
        --Your code
   END
```

And Update

```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[YOUR_TRIGGER_NAME_UPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE] 
   AFTER UPDATE--Here when you updated rows
   AS 
   BEGIN
        select * from inserted --get all inserted (new values) rows 
        select * from deleted--get all deleted (old values) rows    
        --Your code
   END
```